# Should I wait before removing an ActiveSync relationship after sending a remote device wipe command?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, activesync

The process for terminating users at the company I'm presently working for includes remotely wiping any ActiveSync devices and then removing the ActiveSync relationship. I'm writing a PowerShell script to automate the process and, when I send the remove-ActiveSyncDevice cmdlet after sending the clear-ActiveSyncDevice cmdlet, I get a warning that "the device is waiting to be wiped".

If I remove the device, does that cancel any pending wipe commands?

I've done as much web searching as I can in order to find the answer and I'm just having no luck. I would assume that Exchange would give me a more informative warning if removing the device would cancel the wipe request, but since there's so little detail in the warning I just can't be sure.

:edit:
Just thought I would add a bit more detail regarding the research I've already done.
[MS Technet article on remove-activesyncdevice](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125032%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx)
[MS Technet article on clear-activesyncdevice](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa995904%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx)

I have done numerous web searches with multiple search engines using keywords I would expect for this query. I have also searched the Exchange TechCenter on Technet (I have not yet asked this question there). I've also asked several of my colleagues at work, all of whom assume that the wipe command is still processed after removing the partnership, but none of them have any references to back that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems no one knows the answer.

I dug up an old phone and tested. Here is my test scenario:

Add the account to the phone and sync with Exchange
Power off the phone
Send wipe command from EMC
Remove partnership in EMC
Power phone back on
Open e-mail and sync with Exchange

The result was that the e-mail client on the phone reconnected the mailbox and created a new partnership with Exchange. The wipe command was not queued and was obliterated along with the first partnership.

So the answer is: Yes, wait until confirmation that the phone has been wiped before removing the partnership.